# Any way to get the public key of an address?

Tags: smart-contracts, address, public-key

I am developing a dapp where I need the public key of an address of the user, is it possible to get the public key in the contract (using SmartPy)? Or even on the client side using taquito or any other library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do from inside a contract. But you can use the following RPC:

https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-manager-key

**Example:**

https://florencenet.smartpy.io/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1aWXP237BLwNHJcCD4b3DutCevhqq2T1Z9/manager_key

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The above link only gives me the public key for the manager, right? And not of the users, right?

Comment: `tz1`, `tz2`, `tz3` are implicit accounts. And manager_key is their public key, where the `tz*` address is the hash of the public key.

Comment: Right, I got a lil confused...

Answer (score 5):

In the contract, you cannot obtain the public key from an address but if you are given both the public key and the address you can check that the public key corresponds to the address. In Michelson, assuming you have the address and the public key at the top of your stack this is done with `HASH_KEY; IMPLICIT_ACCOUNT; ADDRESS; COMPARE; EQ`.

In the client, you can use the RPC linked in @rodrigo-quelhas' answer but it will only work if the public key for the account has been revealed on chain. Usually revelation is done just before the first transfer from the implicit account.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so using tzkt API https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Accounts_GetByAddress

I think its the easiest method
use this [https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/{address}](https://api.ghostnet.tzkt.io/v1/accounts/%7Baddress%7D)

Answer (score 0):

On the client side with Taquito, there is `getManagerKey()` function in `@taquito/rpc` package to get it from rpc node.  Here is the [typedoc](https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_rpc.rpcclient.html#getmanagerkey) for your reference.
Also, note that an address is the hash of a public key, it shouldn't be reversible by computation. So it only works for the address already revealed on a chain and the rpc node provides mapping.